# Getting additional information (additional_data) form Magento 2 payment Object

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway

I am working on a payment gateway for a mobile wallet. I have created an extra field on payment page on checkout

```
<input name="payment[my_number]" required class="text" placeholder= "Enter My Number", data-bind="input: getMyNumber(), textInput: 'value', value: myNumber"  >
```

which is displaying perfectly

My data assign observer looks like this

```
namespace Myvendor\Mypayment\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Payment\Observer\AbstractDataAssignObserver;
class DataAssignObserver extends AbstractDataAssignObserver
{
/**
 * @param Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $method = $this->readMethodArgument($observer);
    $data = $this->readDataArgument($observer);
    $paymentInfo = $method->getInfoInstance();
    if ($data->getDataByKey('my_number') !== null) {
        $paymentInfo->setAdditionalInformation(
            'my_number',
            $data->getDataByKey('my_number')
        );
    }
}
}
```

Renderer for the form looks like this

```
define(
[
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
],
function (Component) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Myvendor_Mypayment/payment/form',
            myNumber: ''
        },
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super()
                .observe([
                    'myNumber'
                ]);
            return this;
        },
        getCode: function() {
            return 'Mypayment';
        },
        getData: function() {
            return {
                'method': this.item.method,
                'additional_data': {
                    'my_number': this.myNumber()
                }
            };
        },
        getMyNumber: function() {
            return _.map(window.checkoutConfig.payment.mypayment.myNumber, function(value, key) {
                return {
                    'value': key,
                    'my_number': value
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
);
```

Finally I am accessing my number like this

```
/* @var  \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $paymentDO*/
    $paymentDO = $buildSubject['payment'];
    $payment = $paymentDO->getPayment();
    $myNumber = $payment->getAdditionalInformation('my_number');
```

Which is giving me an empty string instead of the dumber submitted,

I am not getting any error on the log so am not quite sure where am going wrong,

I will highly appreciate assistance.

Thanks.

Comment: What version and edition of Magento 2 are you using?

Comment: @AndréFerraz I am using 2.10

Comment: In which table your value is stored? Have u created Attribute for this? Try to put Random value like '978454121545` & search in whole DB

Comment: I am creating a field on the payment step of checkout where a customer can enter the value "myNumber" to picked by additional data observer and added to the payment object then accessed by client and sent  to gateway . I only get to save on database after I have a response. I am however able to pick the posted data on submit which does include {"method":"mypayment","additional_data":{"my_number":"971*****08"}}}. I suspecting I am getting it wrong wither on the ko data binding or on the data observer

Comment: @MosesN.Njenga ,I am trying to add custom field. where exactly I can write the last piece of code in your question, so i can access the variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I Finally figured this out. Going by the number of similar questions, I feel it may be of use to a few people

Following the example of paypals PayflowProAddCcData observer, I modified my observer to

```
namespace Myvendor\Mypayment\Observer;


    use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
    use Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
    use Magento\Payment\Observer\AbstractDataAssignObserver;
    use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface;
    use Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface;

    class DataAssignObserver extends AbstractDataAssignObserver
    {
        /**
         * @param Observer $observer
         * @throws LocalizedException
         */
        public function execute(Observer $observer)
        {
            $data = $this->readDataArgument($observer);

            $additionalData = $data->getData(PaymentInterface::KEY_ADDITIONAL_DATA);
            if (!is_array($additionalData)) {
                return;
            }

            $paymentModel = $this->readPaymentModelArgument($observer);

            $paymentModel->setAdditionalInformation(
                $additionalData
            );

        }
    }
```

The rest of the code remains the same and am able to access the value from my custom field

Answer (score 1):

Add the below function in your payment model file. Do not add key in setAdditionalInformation() otherwise, it will return old data instead of new data

app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Payment.php

```
public function assignData(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $data)
        {
            parent::assignData($data);
            $this->getInfoInstance()->setAdditionalInformation($data->getData());
            return $this;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the part i've been missing in my specific implementation.